# Open .scn file using URL

Tags: swift, scenekit

There are several questions and answers regarding the question I am asking. BUT I found that none of them works.

Here is the situation: I have a `.scn` file, namely, `test.scn`, in my Files folder.
When I tried to load it through the following code

```
let scnURL = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!.appendingPathComponent("test.scn")
do {
    let savedScene = try SCNScene(url: scnURL, options: nil)
} catch {
    print("Fail")
}
```

I always see "`Fail`" message. Could anyone help me?

Added: following the comment of lorem ipsum, I printed error and it just says as follows:

```
Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=259 "The document "test.scn" could not be opened."
```

Comment: Use `print(error)` instead of fail

Comment: What is your goal? Do you want to load the Geometry from the SCN-File and put it on Scene or do you want to load the SCN-File as the entire Scene Graph? Are you required to load the File by using URL? Or could it be any other way to load it?